# Android Picasso set previously loaded image as a placeholder

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I'm loading smaller quality version of image with `Picasso`, and if user clicks on that image in a list, then new `Activity` opens where I'm showing full quality version of image also with `Picasso`.

Problem is that full quality version of image is large so it takes some time to load it.

I would like that during that period previously loaded smaller quality version of image is shown. Picasso would show it instantly because it was already loaded on previous Activity.

I tried to implement it by call Picasso method twice like this:

```
Picasso.get().load(url_small_quality).into(imageView)
Picasso.get().load(url_full_quality).into(imageView)
```

but I think it skips `load(url_small_quality)` because `imageView` is empty for some time until `url_full_quality` is loaded.

I tried to run only `load(url_small_quality)` and then image is loaded instantly as it should, because it was previously loaded and stored.

Is there a way to somehow set previously loaded smaller quality image as a placeholder until full quality image is loaded?

Comment: Calling into() on same id cancels the previous request(https://square.github.io/picasso/) that's why you're unable to load low quality image before high quality one. Can you please check and tell me whether images(where you show small quality) are loaded on your list in offline mode?

Comment: Has your problem solved??

Comment: It has not, I tried your answer and comments, and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably picasso is cancelling your previous request , you can try this

```
 Picasso.get().load(url_small_quality).into(imageView,object:Callback{
            override fun onSuccess() {
                Picasso.get().load(url_full_quality).into(imageView)
            }

            override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
              
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use a drawable as placeholder but that would be a default image

   ```
       Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
   ```
2. You can load your high quality image after successfully loading your low quality image like below(Since there's no direct way to achieve this or other can be to use disk caching but that would require more efforts) :-

   ```
       Picasso.with(context)
       .load(thumb) // small quality url goes here
       .into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(url) // full quality url goes here
                        .placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())
                        .into(imageView);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
   ```

Comment: Thank you, but there is no `onSuccess()` method. There is `onBitmapLoaded` method and I tried to do it there. First I set low quality image to `ImageView`, and then load high quality image. But results were the same, low quality image was not shown, there was blank screen until high quality image was loaded.

Comment: Ok.. is the small url quality url working fine on your listing page?

Comment: What if you enable caching of small url and then re-use that caching on full screen page as well?

Answer (score 0):

As **Astha Garg** said in comments this can't be done:

```
Picasso.get().load(url_small_quality).into(imageView)
Picasso.get().load(url_full_quality).into(imageView)
```

Simply create one more imageview and place it above previous one with thumb and load your high resolution there.

**Java:**

```
Picasso.get().load(url_small_quality).into(IVThumb, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        Picasso.get().load(url_full_quality).into(IVFull, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {

    }
});
```

**xml:**

inside LinearLayout create:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/IVThumb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/IVFull"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```